Question about the Nemytsky operator on $L^p$ space
Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be a bounded open set, $f:\Omega\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a Caratheodory function, i.e. $f(x,\cdot)$ is continuous for a.a. $x\in\Omega$ and $f(\cdot,t)$ is measurable for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$.
We assume that the Nemytsky operator $\mathcal{N}_f$ takes every function from $L^{p}(\Omega)$ (for some $p>1$) to a function in $L^1(\Omega)$, i.e.
$$L^{p}(\Omega)\ni u\mapsto\mathcal{N}_f(u):=f(\cdot,u(\cdot))\in L^1(\Omega).$$
Is it true that for each $u,v\in L^p(\Omega)$ we have that the function:
$$\sup_{t\in [0,1]} |f(\cdot,u+tv)|\in L^1(\Omega)\quad?$$
So we need to prove that $\displaystyle\int_{\Omega} \sup_{t\in [0,1]}|f(x,u(x)+tv(x))|\ dx<\infty$.

Since $f$ is continuous, you have for all $x$ a real number $t(x)\in[0,1]$ such that $$\sup_{t\in[0,1]} = |f(x,u(x)+tv(x)| = f(x,u(x)+t(x)v(x)),$$
with $u(x)+t(x)v(x)$ trivially upper-bounded by an $L^p(\Omega)$ function.
Thus, I believe the question is more a matter of measurability than integrability and searching the key words " measurable selection " could be an idea, see for instance the answer of SBF in this MSE post :
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429961/existence-of-a-continuous-selector-for-a-continuous-optimization-problem

Indeed, if $t$ is measurable all is done.
